# How can I calculate the correlation between two columns in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Let's say that I have the following table

```
create temporary table source( col1 float,  col2 float)
;
insert into source(col1,col2)
values (1, 10020)
      ,(2, 20062)
      ,(3, 30083)
      ,(4, 40099)
      ,(5, 50012)
      ,(6, 60035)
      ,(7, 70087)
      ,(8, 80015)
      ,(9, 90039)
      ,(10,100099);
```

where the `col1`, `col2` are clearly correlated (`col2 = col1 * 10000 + small random quantity`)

Is there any easy way to calculate any kind of correlation coefficient between columns in redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Redshift does not support `CORR(x,y)` or  `COVAR_POP(x,y)`, as it is explicitly mentioned in [Unsupported PostgreSQL functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html).

The (unsupported) PostgresSQL's [corr(y,x)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) would have calculated the correlation coefficient.

Since that function is not supported in Redshift you can **calculate the correlation coefficent in plain SQL** with

```
with t1 as (
    select
        col1
        ,avg(col1) over() as avg_col1
        ,col2
        ,avg(col2) over() as avg_col2
    from source
)
select
  sum( (col1-avg_col1) *(col2-avg_col2)) as numerator
 ,sqrt(sum( (col1-avg_col1)^2)) * sqrt(sum( (col2-avg_col2)^2)) as denominator
 ,numerator/denominator as correlation_coeff
from t1;
```

which gives the following result using the OP dataset:

```
numerator,denominator,correlation_coeff
825098.5,825099.0469993587,0.999999337050066
```

with values :

```
drop table source;
create temporary table source( col1 float,  col2 float)
;
insert into source(col1,col2)
values (1, 10020)
      ,(2, 20062)
      ,(3, 30083)
      ,(4, 40099)
      ,(5, 50012)
      ,(6, 60035)
      ,(7, 70087)
      ,(8, 40015)
      ,(9, 40039)
      ,(10,70000);
```

it gives a correlation coefficient of `0.7599329507675849` which matches  what I get using R to calculate the same:

```
var1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
var2 <- c(10020,20062, 30083, 40099, 50012,60035, 70087, 40015, 40039, 70000)
cor.test(var1,var2, method="pearson")$estimate # 0.759933
```